# Matching as less as possible (greedy-like)

Tags: regex

I have a string that might terminate with multiple `)` characters and possibly followed by some non-character symbols (`,.:;` etc)

I'm testing with this string `this is foo bar)),:` and this regex -> `\){1}\W*?$`
but this matches both `)`. How can I match only the last `)` (no matter how many are there) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this regex -> `\){1}\W*?$` but this matches both `)`. How can I match only the last `)`.

You can use negated character class:

```
\)[^\w)]*$
```

`[^\w)]` will match anything but a `)` or any word char.